# jQuery date function returns wrong values in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date, time

I have this Twitter function with makes a link with the date the tweet was posted. It works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. IE though produces a wrong result: NaN or NaN days ago. The date coming into the function is formatted as such: `Fri Apr 10:19:06 +0000 2012`. Anyone have any thoughts?

```
html += '<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/' + username + '#status_' + data[i].id_str + '">' + data[i].text + ' <i>' + Twitter.daysAgo(data[i].created_at) + '</i></a>';

daysAgo: function (date) {
    var d = new Date(date).getTime();
    var n = new Date().getTime();
    var numDays = Math.round(Math.abs(n - d) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var daysAgo = numDays + ' days ago';
    if (numDays == 0) {
        alert('Works 1');
        daysAgo = 'today';
    } else if (numDays == 1) {
        alert('Works 2');
        daysAgo = numDays + ' day ago';
    }
    return daysAgo;
```

Comment: Did you try to log `d` & `n` ?

Comment: Your date formatting looks wrong. Why is the timezone offset before the year? Where is the day of the month? IE probably doesn't like that. The string-parameter version of the Date constructor is filled with caveats and should generally be avoided.

Comment: The function works fine for me in IE9 with browser mode of IE7. Also works in IE8. What version is it not working in for you?

Comment: Your date of "Fri Apr 10:19:06 +0000 2012" is missing the day number portion? eg. It should look like "Sat Mar 31 10:19:06 UTC+1100 2012"

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I solved it by removing the timezone offset. Seems like a murder of a problem to try and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the timezone offset. Thu May 1- 13:51:30 +0000 2012 became Thu May 1- 13:51:30 2012 and that fixed the NaN error.